# How to call controller method from java script asynchronously

Tags: javascript, actionfunction

I have following code:

```
function PQRS(event,ID){
    delegateResult(ID);
    alert('{!isTrue}');
    if('{!isTrue}' == 'true'){
        alert('hiie');
    }else{
        alert('DO not have any controls to DELEGATE');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here `delegateResult` is an action function, and `isTrue` is variable getting set in delegateResult. But when I call this javascript function, an alert comes up before complete execution of the action function. What should be done in this case?

Comment: Can you add the VF code as well from where this function is called and actionfunction part as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the alert and other stuffs in the oncomplete method. Like this:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="delegateResult" action="{!delegateResult}" rerender="myForm" oncomplete="afterCompletion">
```

Then in your javascript code:

```
function afterCompletion() {
    var isTrue = $("#is_true_element).val();
    alert(isTrue);
    //...
}
```

Please also note I have used a html tag to get the isTrue value. If it is not on the page yet, it should be something like an `<apex:inputHidden>` tag which is rerendered during the actionFunction.

Please Note that {!isTrue} won't rerender in your javascript code. So you will have to place it in the html and rerender that part.

Comment: hey i have one question in onComplete action i want to call another function which will open popup..!!!it has more than 7 arguments and the values are coming from repeater. so i have to take 7 variables..but i can not take variables because of view state issue...!!!!can we have another option ?

Comment: @ChintalSomaiya Unless your view state limit is already used up or the 7 parameters are too large, I don't see it as a huge issue here. However, you can still refer to Javascript remoting if you are really worried about the view state size:https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm